# What is the value of: lim as x appraches -2 from the right of (g(x) + 3g(-x))?

Tags: calculus, limits

Im pretty confused about this question. How would i go about finding out the answer?
I'm specifically confused about the negative x. I got 10 but i feel as if it is wrong.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og7PC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg85e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since we are taking the limit from the left of -2 but are now dealing with a -x we are actually approaching 2 from the right in the 3g(-x). We can see this by considering a simple sequence approaching -2 from the left such as -3, -2.5, -2.25, -2.125, etc. This will approach -2 from the left but if we use -x we get a sequence 3, 2.5, 2.25, 2.125 etc. As such we can now see that the 3g(-x) should be 3 as the limit as x approaches 2 from the right is 1.